# Stanford NLP POS tagger training Unsupported Encoding Exception

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I tried to train my own POS Tagger using Stanford NLP. I followed this guide:
https://medium.com/@klintcho/training-a-swedish-pos-tagger-for-stanford-corenlp-546e954a8ee7#.2r2iaqhm5

My own_model.props File looks like this

```
## tagger training invoked at Tue Jul 08 16:08:39 PDT 2014 with arguments:
model = own-pos-tagger-model
arch = words(-1,1),unicodeshapes(-1,1),order(2),suffix(4)
wordFunction =
trainFile = format=TSV,wordColumn=1,tagColumn=2,./models/data/normal_ner_eng.train_dev
closedClassTags =
closedClassTagThreshold = 40
curWordMinFeatureThresh = 2
debug = false
debugPrefix =
tagSeparator = _
encoding = iso-8859–1
iterations = 100
lang = 
learnClosedClassTags = false
minFeatureThresh = 2
openClassTags =
rareWordMinFeatureThresh = 10
rareWordThresh = 5
search = qn
sgml = false
sigmaSquared = 0.0
regL1 = 0.75
tagInside =
tokenize = false
tokenizerFactory =
tokenizerOptions = asciiQuotes
verbose = true
verboseResults = true
veryCommonWordThresh = 250
xmlInput = null
outputFile =
outputFormat = slashTags
outputFormatOptions =
nthreads = 1
```

This is what my training file looks like (part of it):

```
Cricket nnp i-np    o           
-   :   o   o           
Leicestershire  nnp i-np    i-org           
Take    nnp i-np    o           
Over    in  i-pp    o           
At  nnp i-np    o           
Top nnp i-np    o           
After   nnp i-np    o           
Innings nnp i-np    o           
Victory nn  i-np    o           
.   .   o   o
```

When i execute the command

```
java -classpath stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar:slf4j-api.jar edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -prop models/own_model.props
```

i get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: iso-8859–1
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TSVTaggedFileReader.<init>(TSVTaggedFileReader.java:30)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TaggedFileRecord.reader(TaggedFileRecord.java:115)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.ReadDataTagged.<init>(ReadDataTagged.java:52)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerExperiments.<init>(TaggerExperiments.java:86)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.trainAndSaveModel(MaxentTagger.java:1139)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTraining(MaxentTagger.java:1206)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1839)

Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: iso-8859–1
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:71)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:100)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TSVTaggedFileReader.<init>(TSVTaggedFileReader.java:26)
... 6 more
```

The file is saved in UTF-8 encoding, java version is 1.8.0_77

EDIT: 
I checked the file encoding with 
    file -bi ./models/data/normal_ner_eng.train_dev
it says 
    text/plain; charset=utf-8

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: The exception says you are using encoding "iso-8859–1"

Comment: Edited the questing addressing the encoding mentioned

Comment: In the props file `encoding = iso-8859–1`. The basic Latin-1 generally is supported. Try ISO-8859-1, ISO8859-1, ISO_8859-1.

Comment: Thank you, i did not notice the encoding line in the prop file, i changed it to utf-8 and it works. You might consider writing this as an answer so i can accept it.